# Cannot run program "C:\chromedriver.exe" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

My automation framework was running all fine till today.

Just suddenly started getting this exception today.

```
org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit 
value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program 
"C:\chromedriver.exe" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the browser version and Chromedriver.exe version compatibility. If your browser is autoupdated then use the relavant chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution. This error was occurring due to anti-virus software. The anti-virus software was treating the chrome driver as a threat. So when I stopped anti-virus software, the code worked fine.